# Backup SQL Server database to the cloud or network folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, cloud

I can take a SQL Server backup to a local disk without any problem, but I now need to backup to a cloud disk or network folder that I can access. What are the best practices to do this?

Comment: You could start by reading some documents about it - there must be hundreds of them out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you about the cloud disk but when you backup to a network share you can:

1. Create a network share and assign permissions (I go with full control) to the SQL Server database engine service account (it has to be a domain account)
2. Backup database to this share like that: 
   `BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks TO DISK = '\\MyBackupShare\AdventureWorksFULL.bak'`

You might have to change the SQL Server database engine service account (local account is default).
It's simple. I would recommend using Ola Hallengren's Maintenance scripts though. They give you much more versatility.